# Is it possible to access a vm from Hyper-V server locally?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I've just installed hyper-v server on a new machine for testing purposes and wonders if there is a way to access one of the guests locally?

Or is it only through Hyper-V manager (or remote desktop) from a different machine I can access them?

So the only solution would be to install Windows Server 2008 and add the Hyper-V role to it if I want to be able to work on the server machine as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a product called [ProHVM](https://www.probus-it.com/) that can be use to manage Hyper-V servers locally.

Answer (score 7):

Hyper-V Server is an embedded hypervisor without any graphical UI; in this, it is very similar to a Server Core installation of Windows Server 2008, or to a VMWare ESX server.

You can only do command-line management from the console, and guests are accessible only remotely.

You're right, if you need to run VMs and access them from the same server console, you need a full Windows Server 2008 installation with the Hyper-V role.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the latest version of PSHyper-V. Perform the following (and note the word "locally"):

http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/02/10/enabling-powershell-on-hyper-v-server-2008-r2.aspx

A prudent way to get acquainted with PSHyper-V is to do a full (not core) install of Win Server 2008 R2 onto a dev box, thus being able to confirm the results of a Powershell/WMI command via Hyper-V Manager (also on the dev box). Once well understood, PSHyper-V scripts can then, for example, be used with confidence against an ultra-minimal Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 install.